# Javascript: How to make fade in and out transition when button is pressed?

Tags: javascript, html, css, django

I'm new to Javascript and I want to ask what is the easiest way to create a fade in and out transition? In my case, I have to show/hide div elements. Any help is greatly appreciated!

---

The javascript for my form is shown below

```
function registerNext(){
    document.querySelector(".first_name").style.display = "none";
    document.querySelector(".last_name").style.display = "none";
    document.querySelector(".email").style.display = "none";
    document.querySelector(".password1").style.display = "none";
    document.querySelector(".password2").style.display = "none";
    document.querySelector(".student_number").style.display = "block";
    document.querySelector(".graduation_year").style.display = "block";
    document.querySelector(".degree").style.display = "block";
    document.querySelector(".program").style.display = "block";
    document.querySelector(".btn-next").style.display = "none";
    document.querySelector(".btn-back").style.display = "inline";
    document.querySelector(".btn-signup").style.display = "inline";
    document.querySelector("form.register-form label").style.display = "block";
    document.querySelector("legend.step-2").style.display = "block";
    document.querySelector("legend.step-1").style.display = "none";
}
function registerBack(){
    document.querySelector(".first_name").style.display = "block";
    document.querySelector(".last_name").style.display = "block";
    document.querySelector(".email").style.display = "block";
    document.querySelector(".password1").style.display = "block";
    document.querySelector(".password2").style.display = "block";
    document.querySelector(".student_number").style.display = "none";
    document.querySelector(".graduation_year").style.display = "none";
    document.querySelector(".degree").style.display = "none";
    document.querySelector(".program").style.display = "none";
    document.querySelector(".btn-next").style.display = "block"; 
    document.querySelector(".btn-signup").style.display = "none"; 
    document.querySelector(".btn-back").style.display = "none";
    document.querySelector("form.register-form label").style.display = "none"; 
    document.querySelector("legend.step-2").style.display = "none"; 
    document.querySelector("legend.step-1").style.display = "block"; 
}
```

The css for my form:

```
.first_name, .last_name, .email, .password1, .password2, legend.step-1{
    display: block;
}

.student_number, .graduation_year, .degree, .program, form.register-form label, legend.step-2{
    display: none;
}

button.btn-next{
    display: block;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    animation: bounce;
}

button.btn-signup{
    display: none;
    float: right;
}

button.btn-back{
    display: none;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

I'm using django so this is what my form looks like the one below.

HTML:

```
<form class="register-form" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <fieldset class="form-group">
        <legend class="step-1">Account Setup</legend>
        <legend class="step-2">Academic Background</legend>
        {{ form | crispy }}
    </fieldset>

    <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn-back" type="button" onclick="registerBack()">Back</button>
        <button class="btn-next" type="button"  onclick="registerNext()">Next</button>
        <button class="btn-signup" type="submit">Sign Up</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Here is one example of how I made my forms in forms.py:

```
email = forms.EmailField(
    label = '', 
    widget = forms.TextInput(attrs = {'placeholder': 'Email', 'class':'email'}), 
    max_length = 60
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking Bhavesh's suggestion by using Animate.css, using javascript is another solution by detecting the button click and adding/removing the class attributes of Animate.css. A sample code of how to do this is shown below.

```
btn_next = document.querySelector("#btn_next");
btn_back = document.querySelector("#btn_back");

btn_next.addEventListener('click', () => { 
    form_group_2.classList.add('animate__animated', 'animate__fadeIn');
}) 

btn_back.addEventListener('click', () => { 
    form_group_2.classList.remove('animate__animated', 'animate__fadeIn');
    form_group_1.classList.add('animate__animated', 'animate__fadeIn');
})
```

where `form_group_1` is the parent div where all the first form group to be hidden after pressing the button will be hidden.

Another solution is using functions instead of the `addEventListener`.

```
 <button class="btn-back" type="button" onclick="registerBack()">Back</button>
 <button class="btn-next" type="button"  onclick="registerNext()">Next</button>




function registerNext(){
    form_group_2.classList.add('animate__animated', 'animate__fadeIn');
}

function registerBack(){
    form_group_2.classList.remove('animate__animated', 'animate__fadeIn');
    form_group_1.classList.add('animate__animated', 'animate__fadeIn');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should try out the style-attribute [opacity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity). E.g. a stylesheet like this will make something fade out when you add the `faded-out`-class. Then youll need to time it with another change with the `dislay: none;`-property after that.

```
.item  {
  transition: 0.5s;
  opacity: 1;
}

.item.faded-out {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Animate.css](https://animate.style/) has several animations that you can use for your project. It has fade in and out animation as well. It is simple to use, you just have to add the class name to the element that you want.

The alternative is using the following code:

```
.fade-in {
animation: fadeIn ease 20s;
}
@keyframes fadeIn {
0% {opacity:0;}
100% {opacity:1;}
}
```